# AngularJS: How a Directive without a Controller can work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

just reading a write up from this link http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers

it was hard me like novice in ng to understand their code sample. just tell me a example where people would write directive without controller ?

### their code

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('directivesModule');

  app.directive('isolateScopeWithController', function () {

    var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {

          function init() {
              $scope.items = angular.copy($scope.datasource);
          }

          init();

          $scope.addItem = function () {
              $scope.add();

              //Add new customer to directive scope
              $scope.items.push({
                  name: 'New Directive Controller Item'
              });
          };
      }],

      template = '<button ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button><ul>' +
                 '<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ ::item.name }}</li></ul>';

      return {
          restrict: 'EA', //Default in 1.3+
          scope: {
              datasource: '=',
              add: '&',
          },
          controller: controller,
          template: template
      };
  });

}());
```

Directive usage:

**Attribute**: `<div isolate-scope-with-controller datasource="customers" add="addCustomer()"></div>`

**Element**: `<isolate-scope-with-controller datasource="customers" add="addCustomer()"></isolate-scope-with-controller>`

How we can pass customer data directly to directive. basically we have model in controller and populate model and then pass that model data to directive via isolated scope or directive use controller scope. I am very confused the how above code can work, please help me to understand. thanks

Comment: The code is misleading. The directive *has* controller.

Answer (score 5):

The scenario that is being considered implies that the directive will be used in a part of the application, that already has a declared controller, the scope of which contains the properties `datasource` and `add`. In turn, new controllers will be instantiated for each of the instances of the directive and will have their own isolate scope.

In reality, it is much more common to create directives that do not have a controller, but rather use the link function. These directives can either rely on the parent controller, sometimes perform DOM manipulation, bind to JS events or simply serve as means to encapsulate part of your application.

You can find a good example of a directive that does not create its own controller [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m28mdgSnojgNsb6WovMD?p=preview). It is taken from the Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-adds-event-listeners). You will find that it does not even belong to a parent scope in this case meaning that no controller is involved. In reality, an element like this would most probably report to a parent controller, which would then do something with the position.

You can read more about directives, the link function, and how directives work with controllers [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).